# Validate cells in a grid

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, devexpress, cell

I'm working in a project where I need to validate an group of cells in one specified column when the user click one button. My validation only can be called inside this method not when the cell value change, or something else, I repeat I need to validate the cells only inside this method , not outside.

The events CustomDrawCell, CellStyleChange, ValidateRows, etc. They call themselves automatically and it's not my purpose in this problem. I need to call something when I need to call it, not in other moment.

I try with the StyleFormatCondition but gave me problem because it's work for the column inself not for specified cells.

My validation is very simple, I need to recover the cell value execute a comparison with other values and then paint the background color of the cell if the comparison return true.

For example :

```cs
if (Math.Abs(cellValue- value1 - value2) > EPSILON)
{
  // paint the background color of the cell
}
else
{
  // remains equal
}
```

Would be helpful if somebody have some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can add an extra column with type of `Boolean` to your `GridView.DataSource` and give it a name - «Validated».
Then add to your column `StyleFormatCondition` with expression like `[Validated]`.

And change your method to something like:

```
void YourMethod(GridCell[] groupOfCells)
{
    foreach (GridCell gridCell in groupOfCells)
    {
        bool validated = <Your validation condition goes here>;
        gridView1.SetRowCellValue(gridCell.RowHandle, "Validated", validated);
    }
}
```